# hmvc codeigniter routes modules controller function

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have hmvc structure from https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

modules **content**, create controller **news_event**, and for function **view** to detail view
the structure like this

- modules

  - ...
  - ...
  - content

    - controllers

      - ...
      - **news_event.php**

in **news_event.php**

i having 3 function,index, view and pages

```
 function index() { $this->pages(); }

 function pages($_pages = 1){ ... }

 function view($_id_uri = false){ ... }
```

i had success make

**http://example.com/ci_hmvc/content/news_event/**

become

**http://example.com/ci_hmvc/news_event/**

but its error when its load next view

**http://example.com/ci_hmvc/news_event/view/my-var-uri-friendly-here**

i got error 404, but if i call with this url, success

**http://example.com/ci_hmvc/content/news_event/view/my-var-uri-friendly-here**

my routing code is

```
 $route['news_event'] = 'content/news_event';
 $route['news_event/(:any)'] = 'content/news_event/view/$1';
```

how routes, if i want to access with

**http://example.com/ci_hmvc/news_event/view/my-var-uri-friendly-here**

or this

**http://example.com/ci_hmvc/news_event/my-var-uri-friendly-here**

Answer (score 1):

If your using a route file from within the module folder, the route name must start with the module name.

**modules/content/config/routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'content';

$route['content/'] = '';
```

You could add the route in the normal routing file

**application/config/routes.php**

```
$route['news_event'] = 'content/content/news_event';
```

The idea behind hmvc is to **not** call a module via the routing method, but rather call the module within the system itself(view or controller)

```
Modules::run('module/controller/method', $args);
```

Comment: I respectfully disagree about the URL vs System calls. Calling a module via a URL directly allow independence of that module which in return allows better segregation. Using the system forces you to have some sort of proxy to Module::run the modules.